# tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn inputs sequence_length

Tags: tensorflow

```
sequence_size = [4, 2, 3] ### batch_size:4  num_steps:2  embedding_size: 3
num_units = 2
dummy_sequences = np.array([[[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]],
                            [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]],
                            [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]],
                            [[1.0, 2.0, 3.0], [4.0, 5.0, 6.0]]])
fw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units)
bw_cell = tf.nn.rnn_cell.BasicLSTMCell(num_units)

inputs = tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float64, shape=sequence_size)
encoder_outputs, encoder_state = tf.nn.bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw=fw_cell, cell_bw=bw_cell,
                                                                 inputs=inputs, sequence_length=sequence_size,
                                                                 dtype=tf.float64)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    output, state = sess.run([encoder_outputs, encoder_state], feed_dict={inputs: dummy_sequences})
    print(output, state)
```

I coded an example to test the usage of `rnn` in tensorflow, and I encountered a problem with the parameter `sequence_length`. If I remove the parameter `sequence_length`, the code will run correctly. So, what is the correct way to set `sequence_length`. It confused me a lot because I have already set `sequence_length` in the order of `batch_size`, `num_steps` and `embedding_size`. Thanks a lot for your answer.

And the error is as fllowing:

```
ValueError: Dimension 0 in both shapes must be equal, but are 3 and 4 for 'bidirectional_rnn/fw/fw/while/Select' (op: 'Select') with input shapes: [3], [?,2], [4,2].
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parameter `sequence_length` expects the number of timesteps each sample should be processed for - `num_steps` in your example above. `sequence_length` must be a vector of length `batch_size`.

It is not the shape of input. Suppose your input is as in `dummy_sequence` that is `[4,2,3]`. You have 4 samples, 2 timesteps long, each represented by 3 values.

Hence your `sequence_length` is [2,2,2,2]. In case all samples are of the same length you can omit this parameter. Otherwise, the network will output zero-vector output for each timestep of each sample after maximum timestep for that sample has been reached.